# fullscreen window does not receive mouse move events in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I found a strange bug in Qt on macOS. I reported it to Qt bug tracking system https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-102603. But before this gets fixed, I would be curious whether there is any useful hack or workaround or whether I can fix it somehow in my user code.

So the problem is this:

On macOS, if a window gets shown in fullscreen mode, it fails to receive mouse move events at all. After investigating the issue, I found that this holds UNLESS the mouse cursor was present inside the window geometry BEFORE the window went fullscreen.

I found a hack to solve this issue, which is calling `showMaximized()` before calling `showFullScreen()` which fixed the problem, but it looks very ugly because the window of course first goes maximized and then goes fullscreen. Therefore I would prefer another solution which I hope that kind SO community will help to discover :)

I created a code to demonstrate the issue. If you uncomment `showMaximized()` line, the mouse tracking will work fine because maximized window ensures that the cursor IS INSIDE the window geometry BEFORE going fullscreen. If you leave it commented-out, then the cursor will not be inside the window geometry and mouse tracking will not work.

The code is supposed to show mouse coordinates in the middle of the window. In fullscreen, it shows nothing. I tested it on two macOS machines - macOS 10.15 and 12.3.1 - with various versions of Qt ranging from Qt 5.15.2 to Qt 6.3. It is the same for all of these.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class Widget : public QLabel
{
public:
    Widget()
    {
        setMouseTracking(true);
        setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        auto pos = event->pos();
        setText(QString("(%1, %2)").arg(pos.x()).arg(pos.y()));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;

    // The following line is here to increase the chances that
    // the mouse cursor will not be over the initial window geometry.
    // The purpose is only to help to visualize the problem.

    w.resize(1, 1);

    // If you uncomment the following line, then the mouse cursor is
    // ensured to be inside the window geometry before switching to fullscreen.
    // In that case mouse tracking will work well.
    // If you leave this commented out, mouse tracking will not work in fullscreen.

    //w.showMaximized();

    w.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after several hours of trial and error attempts to find a suitable workaround, I found this code does the job and does not offend my eyes.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTimer>

class Widget : public QLabel
{
public:
    Widget()
    {
        setMouseTracking(true);
        setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        auto pos = event->pos();
        setText(QString("(%1, %2)").arg(pos.x()).arg(pos.y()));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;

    // The following three lines do the trick.
    w.show();
    QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It shows the widget in fullscreen and keeps tracking the mouse moves correctly.

I hope this workaround may help to someone who has the same problem.

Note that proper testing of the problem is very fragile and delicate: for example it makes difference if you run the program from QtCreator by pressing Ctrl+R (in that case the problem goes away even without using `QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents`) or by clicking on button in QtCreator UI (then `QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents` is needed otherwise the mouse does not get registered for the application window for some strange reason). Nevertheless, the code above seems to work for me in all cases.